# Grouping rows in ASP.Net ListView

Tags: asp.net, listview, grouping

I am new to ASP.NET.  I am trying to display my sql results using a list view.  I am using the example for grouping my results by a data field from the [4GuysFromRolla.com website](https://web.archive.org/web/20210301194237/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/091708-1.aspx).  However, I find the way of grouping the items by a data field to be a bit clumsy.  Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested ListView - http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/building_a_grouping_grid_with.html

Comment: I was unsure with using Linq to SQL, but once I added the relationships to the dbml, It worked like a charm.  Thanks.

Comment: Site is offline, but the Wayback Machine pulls through again.
http://web.archive.org/web/20101125093922/http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/building_a_grouping_grid_with.html

Answer (score 0):

I have never used a ListView, but I did do grouping in a GridView.  You can try porting this over to a ListView if you want:

```
Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
    Dim tblGrid As Table = Me.GridView1.Controls(0)
    Dim strLastCat As String = "@"
    Dim row As GridViewRow


    For Each row In GridView1.Rows
        Dim intRealIndex As Integer = tblGrid.Rows.GetRowIndex(row)
        Dim strCat As String = Me.GridView1.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Value

        If strLastCat <> strCat Then
            Dim rowHeader As New GridViewRow(intRealIndex, intRealIndex, DataControlRowType.Separator, DataControlRowState.Normal)
            Dim newCell As New TableCell

            newCell.ColumnSpan = Me.GridView1.Columns.Count
            newCell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(61, 138, 20)
            newCell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)
            newCell.Font.Bold = True
            newCell.Font.Size = New FontUnit(FontSize.Larger)
            newCell.Text = strCat

            rowHeader.Cells.Add(newCell)
            tblGrid.Controls.AddAt(intRealIndex, rowHeader)
            strLastCat = strCat

        End If

    Next

    MyBase.Render(writer)
End Sub
```

The code creates headers each category.  The final version can be viewed here: http://www.truedietreviews.com/diet-reviews/